# Geo Sans Light Font

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know what settings are required for **Geo Sans Light** Font in Latex as can be found [HERE](http://www.dafont.com/geo-sans-light.font).

Comment: I didn't find them directly in [text font catalog](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/alphfonts.html#G)

Comment: Hence my question.

Comment: Any reason for the edit rollback?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like "found here for free" part.

Answer (score 4):

The link you provide refers to a TrueType font (`.ttf`).

You can easily use these if you compile your document with Xe- or LuaLaTeX and use the `fontspec` package. Using the font is then as easy as

```
\setmainfont{Geo Sans Light}
```

is you put the `.ttf` font in your system's system/user font directory, or

```
\setmainfont{GeosansLight.ttf}
```

For more details, read [the `fontspec` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf)

Comment: Two subquestions: 1) No LaTeX? Only Xe or Lua? 2) Does this work for every .ttf?

Comment: @MarioS.E. - no pdfLaTeX, but either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Regarding 1):  `(La)TeX` is a _typesetting language_, and you need an _engine_ to "compile" the source code into output (pdf). The most common engine is `pdf(La)TeX`, but it's also the oldest one. `Xe(La)TeX` and `Lua(La)TeX` are more modern version, with `Lua(La)TeX` being the official successor for `LaTeX3`. In a nutshell, you can mostly take your `(La)TeX` code and switch from one compiler to the other (the biggest change is the handling of input encoding, `Xe-` and `LuaLaTex` relying only but natively on `utf8`).

Comment: Regarding 2):  Yes, it works for any `.ttf` or `.otf` font.